# Delete data from nested array of a cosmosDB document

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have some documents in cosmosDB collection. As part of requirement changes some of the data should be removed from the existing documents. The structure of document in cosmosDB collection is shown below.

```
{
    "IDVALUE": "007999XXXXX",
    "SIGNALS          ": [
        {
            "SIGNAL": "ABC",
            "TIME": 1562064801,
            "VALUE": 520.1
        },
        {
            "SIGNAL": "ABC",
            "TIME": 1562064793,
            "VALUE": 1
        },
        {
            "SIGNAL": "EFG",
            "TIME": 1562064794,
            "VALUE": -33
        },
        {
            "SIGNAL": "EFG",
            "TIME": 1562064795,
            "VALUE": -1
        },
        {
            "SIGNAL": "PQR",
            "TIME": 1562064850,
            "VALUE": 8
        },
        {
            "SIGNAL": "PQR",
            "TIME": 1562064852,
            "VALUE": -14
        },
        {
            "SIGNAL": "XYZ",
            "TIME": 1562064793,
            "VALUE": 168
        },
        {
            "SIGNAL": "XYZ",
            "TIME": 1562064794,
            "VALUE": 180
        }
    ],
    "id": "4be4caff-a33a-7127-2ef6-13fd4df5555",
    "_rid": "TUg6AJtgAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/TUg6AA==/colls/TUg6AJ=/docs/TUg6AJtgSAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"0100d9b7-0000-2300-000-5d0000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1562065035
}
```

As per requirement I have to remove some signals from the nested array of all documents. Suppose If i want to delete  only PQR and XYZ from the array, Is it possible to do a delete like this? 
If yes how to achieve that?
I am not using any IDE, doing development in Azure portal only.

Comment: You mean through the code or portal itself?

Comment: Since I am doing development in portal it will be good if there is any solution which works in portal. But If it is not possible from portal, then scala code in intelliJ is fine.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve this,

(i) Using [`CosmosDB Data explorer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/data-explorer), you can just delete the sub-array within the document and click on Update

[image]

(ii)Cosmos DB doesn't support partial updates now with code. It seems the team is actively working on this feature. As an alternative solution, you  could update the entire document in the stored procedure.

Comment: I just tried the first method using CosmosDB data Explorer, But it seems like we have to update each and every document available in DB.

Comment: But in my case number of documents are more than 10K. Is there any query which will help me to find out a particular signal and delete from all documents?

Comment: you need to write an SP as i mentioned above